# Zip list completable

Tags: android, rx-java

I have the class Sound which contains a media player, I want to write a function that receives a list of sound and play them all, that function should return a 
Completable

```
interface MediaPlayer {
    fun play(): Completable
}

class Sound(val title, val mediaPlayer: MediaPlayer)

//In other class, we have a list of sound to play
val soundList = List<Sound>(mockSound1, mockSound2,..,mockSound10)

fun playSound(): Completable {
    return mockSound1.play()
}

fun playAllSounds(): Completable {
    soundList.forEach(sound -> sound.mediaPlayer.play()) //Each of this will return Completable. 

//HOW to return Completable
return ??? do we have somthing like zip(listOf<Completable>)
}


//USE
playSound().subscrible(...) //Works well

playAllSounds().subscribe()???
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `concat`, from the docs

> Returns a Completable which completes only when all sources complete, one after another.

You can do something like:

```
fun playAllSounds(): Completable {
    val soundsCompletables = soundList.map(sound -> sound.mediaPlayer.play())
    return Completable.concat(soundCompletables)
}
```

Ref: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#concat-java.lang.Iterable-

Comment: I dont think this answer is correct. `concat` subscribes to each `Completable` once the previous one has completed. this corresponds to a sequence of subscriptions

Answer (score 2):

You can try `Completable.merge`. it will subscribe to all the Completables at once.
Here is the [link to the docs](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Completable.html#merge-java.lang.Iterable-)